# SetCustomProperty within OnSaveChange

Tags: development, custom-field-types, spfield, ifieldeditor

Saving Custom Field Type properties using SPField.SetCustomProperty within the IFieldEditor.OnSaveChange event does not seem to work, for reasons explained [elsewhere](http://blog.furuknap.net/custom-field-type-properties-in-sharepoint-buggy-or-not).

I've seen all kinds of <strike>bodges</strike> workarounds for this problem (including using Thread Local Storage or nasty Javascript hacks), but I can't believe this is as Microsoft intended.

Is there a way to get complex column settings from the Add/Edit column page to the column creation events (SPField.OnAdded, SPField.OnUpdated) without resorting to these methods? Or is this just a massive oversight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach might be Gunnar Peipman's - [use reflection to bypass the SetCustomProperty field entirely](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/02/03/sharepoint-temporary-solution-for-getcustomproperty-and-setcustomproperty-errors.aspx). It has worked well for me a few times.You may need to serialize/deserialize data in these prope

```
private void SetFieldAttribute(string attribute, string value)
{
Type baseType; 
BindingFlags flags;
MethodInfo mi;

baseType = typeof(MyCustomField);
flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
mi = baseType.GetMethod("SetFieldAttributeValue", flags);
mi.Invoke(this, new object[] { attribute, value });
}

private string GetFieldAttribute(string attribute)
{
Type baseType;
BindingFlags flags;
MethodInfo mi;
baseType = typeof(MyCustomField);
flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
mi = baseType.GetMethod("GetFieldAttributeValue", 
                            flags, 
                            null, 
                            new Type[] { typeof(String) }, 
                            null);
object obj = mi.Invoke(this, new object[] { attribute });

if (obj == null)
    return "";
else
    return obj.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Now that's suitably outlandish to earn an upvote at least. Love Gunnar's take on the subject: "... parts of SharePoint need brutality and violence to work like expected"

Comment: Agreed, that's what I thought - but it works, and it's tidier than storing the properties in Thread Local Storage. That can work too - but is God-awful to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

I have been using SetCustomProperty in a recent project. The way that it was implemented was to create a new Field Type and inherit from SPField.
A custom field type xml field type was then created and stored in 12HIVE\TEMPLATES\XML\fldtypes_[projectname].xml and a property schema was described in this xml file for the field type:-

```
    <PropertySchema>
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="MultiImageMaxNoImages"
               DisplayName="Maximum Number of Images"
               MaxLength="1"
               Type="Number">
          <Default>4</Default>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="MultiImageMaxSize"
               DisplayName="Maximum Size of Image (Kb)"
               MaxLength="5"
               Type="Number">
          <Default>1024</Default>
        </Field>
      </Fields>
    </PropertySchema>
```

I then created a couple of public properties in the SPField class which would use the following to save field properties.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The maximum number of images that can be stored in the field.
    /// </summary>
    public int MaxImages
    {
        get
        {
            int maxImages = 4;
            Int32.TryParse(GetCustomProperty(Providers.MultiImageFieldProvider.Properties.MaxNumberOfImages).ToString(),out maxImages);
            return maxImages;
        }

        set
        {
            int maxImages = value;
            SetCustomProperty(Providers.MultiImageFieldProvider.Properties.MaxNumberOfImages,maxImages);
        }
    }
```

The Providers.MultiImageFieldProvider is just a static helper class:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Provider for common SharePoint fields and functions.
    /// </summary>
    public static class MultiImageFieldProvider
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Properties class contains internal names of extra custom properties 
        /// </summary>
        public static class Properties
        {
            // Custom Properties
            public const string MaxNumberOfImages = "MultiImageMaxNoImages";
            public const string MaxSize = "MultiImageMaxSize";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately this doesn't fit the requirements I mentioned. The straightforward data types presented and stored by SharePoint itself (defined in the PropertySchema) require no additional work to support; the SetCustomProperty call in the example being largely redundant in this context. The challenge is in storing anything more than these simple data types.

Comment: OK, sorry I see your issue. Could you explain what is that you are trying to achieve, maybe there is a different way to achieve the result.